# how to input field into group nodes?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I'm working with a street generator right now. I have a single building packed into a node group already.

Next I want to generate these buildings on points that are generated from a mesh line.
As you can see in the gif, all the buildings now are having the same input so they will look exact the same.

My question is if there is a way to use field or something else to randomize the input of each building so they can look different other than having tons of this nodegroup and manually set up the input one by one.
I also notise the input of the nodegroup is a circle instead of diamond, which means i cannot input field information into it.
and I dont know how to make it diamond.

thank you for your time!
[image]

Comment: This question has been asked many times, and unfortunately the answer is still: No, it doesn't work. At least it doesn't work that way. If you instantiate a parameterizable object, you cannot change the parameters afterwards. With `Instance on Points` you create "copies" of an object. And there are no loops in GN. Therefore you would have to pack everything into a single group or structure it differently if you want to approach a solution.

Comment: Thank you quellenform for commenting this issue. I totally see the limit of this method. Will try some other approach and wait for the update about this topic. Once this limitaion is cleared out I will spent time on the next step instead of trying to solve it and waste my time. Many thanks! Have a good day pal!

Answer (score 1):

as a "start" and to learn some "principles" you can use this node setup:

[image]

It is far from being perfect, but maybe it gives you some ideas!

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer Chris! I got your idea of randomizing the scale. Btw the shifting of the roof top is a brillant move! But this is not enough for my project. I need buildings to be different in a more foundamental way like different floor numbers or more rolls of windows. I think quellenform's answer explain the main issue of this method. It creates "copies" of mesh and can not be altered afterwards. But still there is something learnt from your setup! Appreciate it! May you have a wonderful day!

Comment: Thanks, you too!